# Linear regression expression of a non-linear model

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, econometrics, data-transformation, nonlinear

$Y=\frac{x_1x_2}{β_0+β_1x_1+β_2x_2}$

It was written on some slide of my econometrics class that such a model could be expressed in the form of a linear model, but I am struggling to derive it by myself.

Here is what I have attempted so far:

$\frac{1}{Y} = \frac{\beta_0+\beta_1x_1+\beta_2x_2}{x_1x_2}$

$\frac{1}{Y} = \frac{\beta_0}{x_1x_2}+\frac{\beta_1x_1}{x_1x_2}+\frac{\beta_2x_2}{x_1x_2}$

$\frac{1}{Y} = \frac{\beta_0}{x_1x_2}+\frac{\beta_1}{x_2}+\frac{\beta_2}{x_1}$

$Y^*=0 + \beta_0X_1^*+\beta_1X_2^*+\beta_2X_3^*$

where $X_1^*=\frac{1}{x_1x_2}$, $X_2^*=\frac{1}{x_2}$ and $X_3^*=\frac{1}{x_1}$

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! I like your middle equation. Why do you have a problem with lacking an intercept?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's a good question that you raise lol. I felt like there should be one but I could run the model without intercept... I have edited my post and corrected for the re-inversion mistake. What do you think ?

Comment: Try it only with y=x_1/beta0, and see what happens, maybe try a few values.

Answer (score 1):

You had it before you removed all of your work.

$$
\dfrac{1}{Y}=\beta_0\dfrac{1}{x_1x_2}+\beta_1\dfrac{1}{x_2}+\beta_2\dfrac{1}{x_1}
$$

The $\dfrac{1}{x_1}$, $\dfrac{1}{x_2}$, and $\dfrac{1}{x_1x_2}$ are then nonlinear basis functions of the original variables.

Yes, the inversion lacks an intercept, but linear models don’t require intercepts. [It’s often advisable to include an intercept in your model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/7948/247274), but an intercept-free linear model remains a linear model.